# How to disable buttons in c# window form application before entering some text in textboxes

Tags: c#

i want that when i am entering some text in my win form text boxes my buttons are disable till that time and when i finished entering my text in text boxes my buttons become enable.
i tried button.Enable=false at form load button this is not full fill my requirement

Comment: If `button.Enable = false;` doesn't work, then I'm not sure what else will. (And, by the way, it should be `button.Enabled`, not `button.Enable`.)

Comment: Please tell us what's wrong with your current solution and show us some code so that we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 3):

> i tried button.Enable=false at form load button this is not full fill my requirement

That should work to disable the buttons (note the property is called Enabled, not Enable).  Perhaps something else is enabling them after you disable them?

You can also set the initial state to disabled in the form designer, or in the [Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.load(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the form (rather than when load buttons are clicked).

As for enabling them, you can add a [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event to the text box(es) in question.  When the event fires, see if all of the required text boxes have text in them, and enable/disable your button appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

In page load set button.enabled = false;

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;    
    }
```

Then you can enable the button when you start typing something in the textbox.

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = true; 
    }
```

Can you tell us what is your requirements? If you can't set the button.enabled = false in the page load, you can use the designer to set the property to false.